# Power BI Report Embed In Static Web Page : Issue with Capacity to generate token

Tags: html, powerbi-embedded

I am developing a Web Page [simple html, CSS, JavaScript] and require embedding Power BI reports which is developed by **other teams** within the same organization. I followed required step to get **Service Principal account**, update **security group** and add Security group in Power BI admin as well as added Service Principal access in Power BI workspace whose report I need to embed. So far all looks good, up and running.

Now after few days I started received error with following.
***"You have exceeded the amount of embed token that can be generated on a shared or ProPlus capacity. You need to purchase Azure capacities to generate embed tokens. ***“

*My question here is about Azure Capacity (based on above error)*.

**Case 1:** Is that something I need to buy since I have Azure AD App [ Service Principal] and my web app is calling those API to embed?

**OR**

**Case 2:** The teams who built that report in Power BI with Pro Account, must buy Capacity? Also, should they need to buy Premium account for this?

Please let me know which scenario [Case 1 or Case 2] is applicable here. Please let me know if there are some best practices available to refer to apply for this process.

I went with all require steps to configure and embed app however with above error, I am looking resolution for capacity error and seeking advice whether I need to approach for Capacity or Power BI Application development team. what step need to take here to resolve this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using [GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-in-group) API, the report must be in a workspace, which is assigned to a dedicated capacity, i.e. [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/power-bi-embedded/). If it isn't, [you have a limited number of tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/move-to-production#development-testing), which can be used during the development process. When you move to production, you must assign the workspace to a dedicated capacity - see [Move your embedded app to production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/move-to-production).

The capacity must be bought my the organization, in which tenant the report is published, so in your case, I guess this is case  #2.